# Best practice for async functions with only synchronous contents?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

Say I have a virtual member function that would be called *asynchronously*:

```cs
class Command {
    public abstract Task<object> Execute();  // Meant to be async for implementations
}
class Caller {
    Command command;
    public async Task Call() {
        await command.Execute();  // Command.Execute is always called with `await`
    }
}
```

For most of the cases, the implementation is just a normal async logic:

```cs
class NormalCase : Command {
    public override async Task<object> Execute() {
        await ...;  // Some async works
        return ...;
    }
}
```

But there are indeed some cases where the derived implementation is just meant to be done synchronously -- i.e. no `await` is needed.

```cs
class SyncCase : Command {
    public override async Task<object> Execute() => 1;  // Just a synchronous value
}
```

This of course works, but it will bring up a compilation warning (CS1998).
Putting a `#pragma` option can suppress the warning, but there are implementations in many separate files and I'll have to put `#pragma`s everywhere. (thanks a lot, Unity!)
So let's just put this solution aside.

I've also tried several other possible solutions, but none of them works well:

```cs
class Solution1 {
    public override async Task<object> Execute() {
        await Task.Delay(1);  // Just NASTY
        return 1;
    }
}
class Solution2 {
    public override Task<object> Execute() => 1;  // Will cause upstream calls to break
}
class Solution3 {
    public override Task<object> Execute() =>
        new Task<object>(() => 1);  // Same, it breaks upstream logic
}
```

Given this situation, what is the best practice?

Comment: The answer is - don't. You're lying to the consumer of the function. If, and only if, the result is already available, use `Task.FromResult()`. Otherwise *make* the method async by using `Task.Run()` to run the blocking code in a separate thread

Comment: BTW using `object` is a bad idea too. You should either return the actual type or make the class generic if the type can change.

Comment: Don't think I'd recommend using `Task.Run` - see [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) and particularly [Don't use Task.Run in the implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd really like not to, but PropertyDrawer in Unity doesn't really support generic classes, therefore using `object` was kind of forced :-(

Comment: @NianyiWang you didn't say you're using Unity. In that case you'll have to cast the results to `object`. In this case though, it's even more important to *not* block.

Comment: `thanks a lot, Unity!` .. ^^ this is a general `c#` thing .. nothing Unity can change about that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is - don't. You're lying to the consumer of the function. Imagine calling a method you assumed was asynchronous to do something in the background, only to find that your UI froze for 10 seconds.

If, and only if, the result is already available, use [Task.FromResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-6.0)

```
class StaticCase : Command {
    
    public override Task<object> Execute() => Task.FromResult((object)1); 
}
```

Otherwise make the method async by using Task.Run() to run the blocking code in a separate thread:

```
class BlockingCase : Command {
    
    public override async Task<object> Execute() 
    {
        var result=await Task.Run(()=>SomeHeavyWork());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I *not* supposed to make any (even synchronous) calls in `Task.FromResult`?

Comment: `Task.FromResult` returns a task in the `Completed` state with the value you provide. It doesn't execute anything. This avoids using a threadpool thread just to return an already existing value. Whether it's OK to execute blocking code before returning that result is up to you.